# Mix several Enumerations into one

Tags: scala

Let's assume that we have the next two **Enumeration**s:

```
object EnumX extends Enumeration {
  val val1 = Value
  val val2 = Value
}

object EnumY extends Enumeration {
  val valA = Value
  val valB = Value
}
```

These enumerations have similar business value and can't be changed. For some reason I'd like to have "new" *type* (let's name it **MixedEnumXY**) which can accept enum values from **EnumX** and **EnumY**:

E.g.

```
val e1: MixedEnumXY = EnumX.val1
val e2: MixedEnumXY = EnumY.valA
```

Is it possible to implement this in Scala?

Comment: `sealed trait` is recommended instead enums in Scala

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use sealed case classes?

```
sealed trait XY
sealed trait X extends XY
sealed trait Y extends XY

object EnumX {
    case object Val1 extends X
    case object Val2 extends X
}

object EnumY {
    case object ValA extends Y
    case object ValB extends Y
} 

val e1: XY = EnumX.Val1
val e2: XY = EnumY.ValA
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want seems hacky to me so you probably should be OK with a hacky solution that relies on implicit conversions:

```
object EnumX extends Enumeration {
  val val1 = Value
  val val2 = Value
}

object EnumY extends Enumeration {
  val valA = Value
  val valB = Value
}

import scala.languageFeature.implicitConversions

object MixedEnumXY extends Enumeration {
  val val1 = Value
  val val2 = Value
  val valA = Value
  val valB = Value

  implicit def fromEnumX(ex: EnumX.Value): MixedEnumXY.Value = ex match {
    case EnumX.val1 => val1
    case EnumX.val2 => val2
  }

  implicit def fromEnumY(ey: EnumY.Value): MixedEnumXY.Value = ey match {
    case EnumY.valA => valA
    case EnumY.valB => valB
  }
}

def test(): Unit = {
  val e1: MixedEnumXY.Value = EnumX.val1
  val e2: MixedEnumXY.Value = EnumY.valA
}
```

The other obvious choice would be to use [Either](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/util/Either.html) or create a similar custom class with your additional logic.

Answer (score 1):

So, I came up with the next DRAFT solution

```
object EnumX extends Enumeration {
  val val1 = Value
  val val2 = Value
}

object EnumY extends Enumeration {
  val valA = Value
  val valB = Value
}

sealed trait MixedEnum {
  def reason: Enumeration#Value
  override def toString: String = reason.toString
}

case class EnumXMix(reason: EnumX.Value) extends MixedEnum
case class EnumYMix(reason: EnumY.Value) extends MixedEnum


object MixedEnum {
  implicit def EnumX2MixedEnum(value: EnumX.Value) = EnumXMix(value)
  implicit def EnumY2MixedEnum(value: EnumY.Value) = EnumYMix(value)
}
```

Now, you can use it the next way:

```
import MixedEnum._
val enumValue1: MixedEnum = EnumX.val1
val enumValue2: MixedEnum = EnumY.valA
val enumSeq: Seq[MixedEnum] = Seq(EnumX.val1, EnumY.valA)

println(enumValue1)
println(enumValue2) 
println(enumSeq)
```

Output:

```
val1
valA
List(val1, valA)
```